# WPF Error: Do not recognize or can not access the member "resource"

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Ok, I have to say that I just started using WPF and I know nothing about XAML, so for my first project with WPF, I'll be trying to build my own app for my own buisness, But im getting a problem trying to get an image resource.

This is what I tried

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="605.027" Width="1042.214" WindowStyle="None" Background="{StaticResource Circuits}">
    <Application.resource>        
        <ImageBrush x:Key="Circuits" ImageSource="Circuits.jpg"/>
    </Application.resource>   
</Window>`
```

But at the `<Application.resource>` line I'm getting the error

> Do not recognize or can not access the member "resource"

and I just dont know what to do

Comment: Here you are not supposed to add "Answered" to title, instead you should just mark the answer by the green tick which you already did.

Comment: ok. thank you, I thought it would be helpful to know that the question was answered when other were looking for something related to this problem, But I wont in the future :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="605.027" Width="1042.214" WindowStyle="None" Background="{StaticResource Circuits}">
    <Window.Resources>        
        <ImageBrush x:Key="Circuits" ImageSource="Circuits.jpg"/>
    </Window.Resources>   
</Window>`
```

Comment: your tip worked, I just added "Imagenes\" to the image source and worked, example: `<ImageBrush x:Key="Circuits" ImageSource="Imagenes\Circuits.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<Application.Resources>
```

So in your exemple :

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Title="MainWindow" Height="605.027" Width="1042.214" WindowStyle="None" Background="   {StaticResource Circuits}">
 <Application.Resources>        
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Circuits" ImageSource="Circuits.jpg"/>
 </Application.Resources>   
</Window>
```

Comment: yup, and It's the same